# Best way to show a specific view in SwiftUI based on the user's logged in status

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My goal is to

- show a `LoginView` when the user first launches the app
- after the user logs in, we should store the token and go to the `HomeView`
- any time the user opens the app in the future, we taken user to the `HomeView` since we have a stored token
- finally, we should log the user out and return them to the login screen if the token has expired

I tried approaches outlined in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrTChgzseVk) and [this medium article](https://paulallies.medium.com/login-logout-flow-swiftui-and-environmentobject-48ea084c5b6e)

At a high level, they both talk about injecting some sort of an Authentication object into the environment, something like:

First we have the authentication class which is an observable object

```
class Authentication: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isValidated = false
    
    func updateValidation(success: Bool) {
        withAnimation {
            isValidated = success
        }
    }
}
```

We then create the authentication object in the main and pass it to the environment

```
@main
struct MySecureApp_App: App {
    @StateObject var authentication = Authentication()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if authentication.isValidated {
                ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(authentication)
            } else {
                HomeView()
                    .environmentObject(authentication)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the login view

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @StateObject private var loginVM = LoginViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var authentication: Authentication

    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                // some login views

                Button("Log in") {
                    loginVM.login { success in
                    authentication.updateValidation(success: success)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then finally in the home view

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject private var homeVM = HomeViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var authentication: Authentication

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
            }.onReceive($homeVM.isUnauthorized) // ignore for SwiftUI syntax {
                authentication.updateValidation(success: false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now while this could work, it seems rather cumbersome to keep passing the authentication object to each and every view.

Is there a way possible that we could inject these StateObjects or environment objects into view models or services ?

In my opinion a good solution might be to set the logout status of the user from the HTTPClient when an API returns an unauthorized response rather than having to check this in every view.

Comment: You need to provide the `Authentication` instance to the api service(s). You haven't shown these or how they are created so I can't be any more specific, but it is just an object so you can assign it or pass it in an initialiser.

Comment: Dependency injection

Comment: Fair enough, both the comments talk about dependancy injection. If you see my last few statements of the question, I ask for specifically how to do this ? Can we inject state objects and environment objects into view models and clients ? My assumption was that we could only do this with SwiftUI views. We can't pass any instance of the Authentication to these services, it needs to be the same StateObject instance that was initialized in the main. How could we do that ?